# Warning CS0618 resolution

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to get rid of 
`Warning CS0618: 'IDtsClipboardService' is obsolete: Use 'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model.IClipboardService' instead`. I am trying to locate `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model` assembly to no avail. Anybody aware what installs it?

I have got SQL Server 2014 installed with Integration Services, SSDTS for VS2017 installed, up to date VS2017 and build tools version 15.

Any clues are warmly welcomed! Thanks

Comment: You'll find it in the GAC. But to extract it, you have to jump through some hoops. Take a look at this walkthrough to see if it helps: http://muxtonmumbles.blogspot.com/2012/08/programmatically-executing-packages-in.html

Comment: hey Aaron, thanks for your reply, the thing is I added this reference and added a `using Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices;` however the intellisense cannot find `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model` I really need to use the suggested `IClipboardService` interface just cannot find the path to it..

Comment: It kind of sounds like either SSIS didn't install everything it should have, or you're missing a .NET framework installation. What's the context here? Are you working on an SSIS Script Task or an application that interfaces with SSIS?

Comment: Just clearing warrnings from building solution projects.. I've got 3.5; 4;4.5; 4.5.2; 4.6; 4.6.1; 4.7.2 support installed.. and not a clue. The official microsoft page shows the API being obsolete, but does not even hint where the new assembly is supposed to be found..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miraculously I have found where **Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model.IClipboardService** is!

According to Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms211237(v%3Dsql.110) - it sits nowhere..

Using `ILDASM.EXE` from `Dev CMD` I started opening every assembly related to IntegrationServices and found out that the inteface I am after sits here:

**Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph.dll**

[image: IClipboardService]